# Apache reverse proxy closing connection with FIN-ACK to origin and chrome

Tags: google-chrome, apache2.4

Apache 2.4.46
Chrome version 87
Origin IIS/10.0

Apache sending FIN/ACK after every response to chrome and origin, in simple words connection keep alive is not working even after "connection : keep-alive" can be seen in request and response header.
This is working well in all non chromium browser like safari and firefox.

Once we clear idle socket in chrome://net-internals/#sockets it works for chrome too.